# Relating data in a Django Model to another model

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have this model.

```py
class AuctionListings(models.Model):
    """
    Model for all the listings listed on the site.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField()
    current_bid = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, max_length=5)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date_last_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    timestamp_last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Title:{self.title}, Date Added:{self.date_added}, Category:{self.category}"

    class Meta:
        """
        Specifies the plural name of the model for the Django Admin Panel.
        """
        verbose_name_plural = "Auction Listings"
```

I want to be able to set the starting bid in Auction Listings when someone creates a new listing. Just like how eBay would do it.
I want the bid to also be able to be updated in the bid model. And that if the listing is deleted, the bid on the listing would also be deleted. Because there is no listing. I've tried using a foreign key but then I get this

You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'current_bid' to auctionlistings without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

This is the bid model I want to relate to the Auction model.

```py
class Bids(models.Model):
    """
    Model to allow one to place bids on listings.
    """
    bid_price = models.ForeignKey(AuctionListings, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listings = models.ManyToManyField(AuctionListings)
```

I just started learning Django and really don't know where to look, so I'll be grateful for some help and explanation on what exactly to do.

Comment: Can one user make one bid for multiple listings? You have a ManyToManyField there. Does that make sense? And then you have another ForeignKey field `bid_price`, shouldn't that be an IntegerField? Something seems off.

Comment: @Ene Paul Multiple listings can be bid on by the same person, that's why I'm using a man to many. I'm using a foreign key for bid price because there should a starting price, and it should relate back to bids to reflect that price. Can't seem to make that happen though.

Comment: Ok, but using a `ManyToManyField` like that means that the user "bids" on multiple listings with that exact `Bid`. Like if a user submitted a bid for 3 listings, there should be 3 different bids, not the same bid submitted for 3 different listings.

Comment: I think you want to use a `ForeignKey` there. It has OneToMany functionality. Like a listing can have multiple bids, but one cannot submit the same Bid to multiple listings.

Comment: I'll implement that. But does Django have something like a foreign key join? Then I can let bid_price be a foreign key that joins on the current_bid.

Comment: Yes it does. I think it's best for you to watch some tutorials on the Django ORM before continuing.